# Special Relativity Kinematics Problem with My Wrong Solution

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics

You are traveling toward a large fixed mirror at a constant relative speed 0.20 c0 . At t = 0, when the mirror is a distance d from you, you emit a light pulse from a lantern and then detect the reflected light pulse 0.80 μs later.

Trying to go about this I got the following:

```
(3.00*10^8)(.80*10^-6) - (.20)(3.00*10^8)(.80*10^-6) =  192 m
```

This however is incorrect. I feel as though this should be the correct answer, but the correct answer is 120 m. Where am I wrong?

Just incase it is unclear I am looking for $d$ in your reference frame from time t=0.

Comment: Is the question to find $d$? If so, could you edit that into your post?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. @NeuroFuzzy is right: you're missing some information in your question. If you edit it so that it's complete, you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: there you go. added.

Comment: Are you looking for $d$ in the mirror's frame or in your frame?

Comment: your frame at time t.

Comment: $(c)0.8\mu s$ is the distance the light be travels out and back.  Why would you care about that entire distance in your calculation?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of this question as someone a distance $2d$ ahead of you releasing a pulse of light (the man in the mirror). In that way, the problem simplifies to "how far can light travel in $0.80 \mu s$?" Solving this will give you the value of $2d$ ($2d = ct$). So divide by $2$ to get $d$, and the calculation is simply $d = ct/2 = 120m$.

EDIT: I should clarify (based on comments). We want the distance in our frame of reference, so we observe everything from the frame of reference where we are not moving. This means the mirror is moving towards us and so is the man in the mirror. However, the speeds are completely irrelevant, since the speed of light is always $c$ in every frame.

At the instant $t=t_0$ the man in the mirror releases a pulse of light moving at speed $c$ away from him and towards us. We are not moving in our frame, so the distance the light must travel to get to us is $2d$, and no less. That is why this calculation makes sense. Knowing the velocity we are travelling is unnecessary.

Comment: Think about it like this: You are not moving in your frame of reference, but the man in the mirror is moving towards you at $0.4c$. His speed is irrelevant though, because the pulse of light is traveling at $c$, of course. So in your frame, the pulse of light does travel $2d$.

Comment: Sorry, we would observe the man in the mirror moving at $\frac{0.2 + 0.2}{\sqrt{1.04}}c=0.392c$, but as I said before, the speed is irrelevant.